Kenmore Series 90 washer will not start back agitating after refilling for rinse cycle
Kenmore 90 series Washer quit working during cycle. Replaced capacitor & motor started working. Washed about 5 loads and it quit after refilling for rinse cycle. I had noticed that the washer would hesitate to restart after refilling with water previous to replacing those parts. If I turn the wash selector switch beside the timer to a different selection the washer will normally start working again and finish the cycle. I to can smell a hot smell when it stops, and the plug will be real warm. It's almost like the motor gets hot trying to restart.I did replace the timer yesterday but that did not correct the problem.
It worked perfectly till it refilled for the rinse cycle and it did not start back agitating. So I turned the timer to a different rinse cycle and it still did not start. then I moved the wash type switch to different setting till it started. once it started I moved it back to the original setting. It then completed the cycle.

Warm plug, hot motor and a hot smell is sign of problems.  Either binding of parts or loose connections, or both.  Might be bad bearing/s to bent parts/shafts or just connections barely holding together, but if not fix soon/now, bad stuff will happen.
